# Hive query to Extract Date and Hour separately from String

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to extract Date and hour from the string column in hive.

Table:
[image]

```
select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dates,'dd/MM/yyyy'))) from dates;

output:

0016-01-01
0016-01-01

select TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dates,'hh'))) from dates;

output:

1970-01-01
1970-01-01
```

Please advise how to take date seperately and hour seperately from the table column.

Comment: (1) removed irrelevant tags (2) replace the picture with text (3) There are many bad ways to store dates/timestamps, but this is one of the worst

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've change the data sample to something more reasonable

```
with dates as (select explode(array('1/11/16 3:29','12/7/16 17:19')) as dates)

select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dates,'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'),'yyyy-MM-dd')  as the_date
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dates,'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'),'H')           as H
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dates,'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'),'HH')          as HH

from    dates
```

---

```
+------------+----+----+
|  the_date  | h  | hh |
+------------+----+----+
| 2016-11-01 |  3 | 03 |
| 2016-07-12 | 17 | 17 |
+------------+----+----+
```